# What markup should be used so that Google generates a knowledge graph for our organization?

Tags: schema.org, json-ld, knowledge-graph

```
<script type='application/ld+json'> 
{
  "@context": "http://www.schema.org",
  "@type": "Organization",
  "name": "",
  "url": "example.com",
  "logo": "example.com/logo.png",
  "image": "example.com/image.jpg",
  "description": "",
  "address": {
    "@type": "PostalAddress",
    "streetAddress": "",
    "addressLocality": "",
    "addressRegion": "",
    "postalCode": "",
    "addressCountry": "Bangladesh"
  },


  "contactPoint": {
    "@type": "ContactPoint",
    "telephone": "+",
    "contactType": "customer service"
  },
  "sameAs": [
            "https:facbook",
            "https:twitter"
        ]

}
</script>
```

Is this code okay to generate a knowledge graph for organization. Or if I want to add this for my landing page how can I add this for only the lading page?

Comment: I don't think Google uses markup from your site for their knowledge graph.  I think they use data from third party sources such as Wikipedia.  See http://searchengineland.com/enhance-google-knowledge-graph-result-case-study-243965

Answer (score 2):

You appear to be talking about two separate things here. What you are describing in your question with the json-ld sample is not used in the knowledge graph rather it is used for rich snippets (AKA structured data) support in Google. This enables Google (where the algorithms deem it appropriate) to show your rich snippets in the results page under your entry.

The knowledge graph on the other hand is a graph database maintained by Google but populated with data sourced from **high authority** sites. There is no way to push data into the graph as Google only populates it based on high authority data (think sites like Wikipedia and similar).

By all means add all the appropriate jon-ld structured data to your site as needed to improve rich snippet support but don't expect it to result in a knowledge graph being created for your organisation.

Comment: This is partially true. Google My Business is the highest authority for the knowledge graph and that relies upon mark up as part of the equation. Secondarily, being listed on sites that take their information directly from the phone book, yellow or white pages, is also required. Scraped sites just do not cut it regardless of any authority. The knowledge graph requires original sources before it will include information from other sites. Cheers!!